# Is there a closed form for this sum? Maybe involves polylogarithm function

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I´m trying to find a property of the polylogartihm function that could help me find a closed form for this sum... maybe is there another way?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{7 - 3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n}{n^3}$$

Answer (score 2):

We have, if $\left|x\right|\le1$
 $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{n}}{n^{k}}=\textrm{Li}_{k}\left(x\right)$$
 where $\textrm{Li}_{k}\left(x\right)$ is the polylogarithm function. Then $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(\frac{7-3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}}{n^{3}}=\textrm{Li}_{3}\left(\frac{7-3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you Marco! But I was thinking about a closed form in terms of well-known mathematical constants. I wrote the argument as a function of the golden ratio, but I haven´t found a relation that helps me go on